# Intando mostrar un vector: Error : no match for 'operator<<'(operand types are 'std::ostream')and std::vector<Persona>

Tags: c++

Buenas noches tiempo atras realice mi primer proyecto de programacion en JAVA, para este utilice arraylist, ahora necesito hacer otro proyecto pero en c++, queria usar  otro arraylist porque simplifican el trabajo, pero en este lenguaje no se como utilizarlo no hay mucho. Si se puede utilizar un arraylist mucho mejor. Tengo el siguiente problema cuando quiero imprimir mi vector.
Error : no match for 'operator<<'(operand types are 'std::ostream')and std::vector

```
vector<Persona> vectorPersonas;
Personas personas = new Persona();
string nombre;
int cedula;
//Solicito esos datos y los seteo
Persona personaAgregada = new Persona(nombre, cedula);
vectorPersonas.pushback(personaAgregada);
for(int i = 0 ; i < vectorPersonas.size() ; i++)
cout << vectorPersonas; //Aqui marca el error
```

Comment: La sintaxis correcta es "vector.push_back()"

Comment: Logre arreglar esa parte, pero ahora no puede imprimir, lo que contiene el vector sale no operator matches.

Answer (score 3):

Mucho ojo porque aquí estás teniendo fugas de memoria:

```
Persona personaAgregada = new Persona(nombre, cedula);
```

`personaAgregada` **no es un puntero**. Si esa línea te compila sin errores es porque estás haciendo una copia del objeto que has creado con `new` ... y de paso te estás olvidando del objeto original, es decir:

```
Persona * temp = new Persona(nombre, cedula); // Creamos un objeto
Persona personaAgregada = *temp;              // Copiamos el objeto
temp = nullptr;                               // perdemos toda referencia al objeto original
```

Pero lo dicho, eso suponiendo que esa línea te llegue a compilar sin errores.

Si `personaAgregada` no es un puntero, **no uses** `new`:

```
// opción 1
Persona personaAgregada = Persona(nombre, cedula);

// opción 2
Persona personaAgregada(nombre, cedula);
```

Y ahora vamos con tu error. El problema que tienes es que no hay ni una sola sobrecarga del operador `<<` que admita un objeto de tipo `vector<Persona>`. Esto no es Java y aquí no hay una función especial `toString()` que convierta absolutamente todo a un string... esas funciones te las tienes que programar:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, std::vector<Persona> const& lista)
{
  // Aqui el codigo para imprimir la lista por pantalla
}
```

Como por ejemplo:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, std::vector<Persona> const& lista)
{
  for( Persona const& persona : lista )
  {
    os << persona << '\n';
  }

  return os;
}
```

Claro que ahora te falta otra sobrecarga para `Persona`:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, Persona> const& persona)
{
  // Tu codigo aqui
}
```

Comment: Hay otra forma de realizarlo?, estoy trabajando con archivos, lo que pasa es que me acorde que en un proyecto pasado utilice arrayList ahorita no me quiero complicar. De ir metiendo personas dinamicamente..

Comment: @Keylor no se trata de complicarse o no ... en C++ no existen los metadatos que tienes en Java, no hay introspección que permita escribir código dinámico en tiempo de ejecución ... en C++ todo tiene que estar codificado en tiempo de compilación y nadie salvo tu sabe cómo tratar un objeto de tipo `Persona` ... el compilador no lo va a hacer por ti

Comment: *Si personaAgregada no es un puntero, no uses new:* Como complemento:  Solo se debe usar new cuando se quiere que el objeto siga en memoria. Si nada más se crea un objeto en una función y solo se va a usar en esa función, lo ideal es llamar al constructor a secas. Por otro lado si se va a retornar el objeto si hay que usar new, para que el compilador no se trague el objeto.

Comment: @Gabitohh eso no es del todo cierto ... existe la _Return Value Optimization_, la semántica de movimiento y otras características de las que puedes beneficiarte si el objeto no se ha creado con `new`. Como todo, depende de las características del objeto y del uso que se le vaya a dar